# How to setup personalized Ads in admob

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, admob

I have made a mobile app with Flutter and I use Admob.
Users started to use my app and when I check on Firebase it says users view non personalized ads. What can I do to make Admob show personalized Ads to my users?

Comment: This is probably because they selected to do so, as due to privacy regulations maybe Admob and so on don't allow this. Maybe you need to implement an Admob thing that asks this question and if it doesn't, it defaults to non-personalised ads.

Comment: Jakub, did you manage to get around this? Also could you describe what happens if you try to test with personalised ads? I am using google_mobile_ads (for banner and interstitial ads) and admob_consent packages. No matter what I do on Android if the tracking is revoked I get LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [])). On the other hand test ads and real ads on iOS test device seem to work fine.